# Access 2016. Expression

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table t01PriceList with fields including. "Date","LatestPrice01","StockNumber01".
Another table t01StockItem with fields including "LatestPrice02", "StockNumber02".
I want an expression in t01StockItem that returns the amount from "LatestPrice01" at the latest date. There are multiple records in t01Pricelist against the same StockItem.

I tried Dlookup("LatestPrice01","t01PriceList",Dmax(Date))

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a query to retrieve the latest prices:

```
Select 
    StockNumber01, LatestPrice01
From 
    t01PriceList As A,    
        (Select StockNumber01, Max([Date]) As LatestDate
        From t01PriceList
        Group By StockNumber01) As T
Where 
    A.StockNumber01 = T.StockNumber01 And
    A.Date = T.LatestDate
```

Then join this with t01StockItem on the StockNumber.